# Correct usage of fft2 and fftshift for shape from shading

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, fft, shapes, ifft

I am attempting to recreate a classical shape from shading algorithm seen in the Trucco/Verri text "Introductory Techniques for 3d Computer Vision", but I am having a hard time understanding the fft function in matlab. Essentially, I need to use the integrability constraint to get the depth (Z) of an image. I am not sure when to use fftshift or not in this scenario. Here is the code I have so far. Based on http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285244
I basically wrapped all my fft2s in fftshifts, but I don't think this is the correct usage. Could someone please explain to me the usage and what I am doing wrong? Thank you. Basically, I'm trying to take my p and q (values which are the updates based on pixel intensities) transform them into the Fourier domain so as to use them in the equation C. Then I want to transform the Equation C back to the time domain because that will give me Z the depth. I also want to update P and Q based on C in the Fourier Domain.

```
    wx = (2.* pi .* x) ./ m; 
    wy = (2.* pi .* y) ./ n; 
    wx = ifftshift(wx); wy=ifftshift(wy);

    Cp = fftshift(fft2(fftshift(p))); 
    Cq = fftshift(fft2(fftshift(q)));
    C = -1i.*(wx .* Cp + wy .* Cq)./(wx.^2 + wy.^2); 
    Z = abs((ifft2(ifftshift(C)))); 
    p = ifftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(1i * wx .* C))); 
    q = ifftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(1i * wy .* C)));
```

Comment: It would help if you could say a little more about what you are trying to do.  As it stands, your code will not run, and is without any context about what the pieces mean.

Comment: Hi I added some explanation of the code, I hope that is clearer now, basically I want to transform p and q to the fourier domain, create another equation C in the fourier domain and then go back to the Time Domain and the equation C should give Z.

Answer (score 16):

This is a tricky question because in general there is not a right answer.  There may be some wrong answers though.  I will try to explain.  If the answer get a little bit too wordy, you can always just skip down to the summary section and see if it helps.

## Gotchas

**Gotcha #1:**

When you use Matlab's `fft` (or in your case `fft2`) function, the first element of the output (in your case `X(1,1)`) represents the [DC bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_bias). If you subsequently call `fftshift` on your output, everything gets shifted around in a way that places the DC bias at the center.  In the 2-dimensional case, it looks something like this:

[image: 2-Dimensional fftshift]

Notice that the point that was at the top-left corner of block 1 gets moved to the center. While this is a perfectly valid representation of the data, we have to be careful because we have *changed the meaning* of the (1,1) bin.  If I were to attempt an inverse transform at this point, the output would be wrong!

```
B = ifft2(fft2(A));            % B is equal to A
C = ifft2(fftshift(fft2(A)));  % C is not equal to A
```

**Gotcha #2:**

The `ifftshift` function should be thought of as the inverse of the `fftshift` operation.  It should not be thought of as a shift that applies to `ifft` operation.  For this reason, I feel that the function names are very misleading.

In my experience, it is most common for an `ifftshift` to *precede* an `fft`/`ifft` function, and for an `fftshift` to follow `fft`/`ifft` function.  In fact, I would go so far as to say that if you ever find yourself doing one of the following things, you have probably made a mistake:

```
B = ifftshift(ifft(A));        % Don't do this
C = fft(fftshift(A));          % Don't do this either
```

The following helpful note is found in the [Matlab documentation for `ifftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifftshift.html)

> **Note:**  `ifftshift` will undo the results of `fftshift`. If the matrix `X` contains an odd number of elements, `ifftshift(fftshift(X))` must be done to obtain the original `X`. Simply performing `fftshift(X)` twice will not produce `X`.

For example:

```
B = ifftshift(fftshift(A));    % B is equal to A
C = fftshift(fftshift(A));     % C is not equal to A
```

**Gotcha #3:**

The DFT has many interesting properties, one of which is that the DFT of a real, even sequence is real and even. We can often use this fact as a simple sanity check.  If we put a real, even sequence into the `fft` function and get back something back that is not real and even, we have a problem.

We must take careful note of what an even function looks like when it comes to the DFT. The sequence `3 2 1 0 1 2 3` appears to be even, right?  The left half is a mirror image of the right half. This *would be* true if the fourth element of the sequence represented `t=0`.  However, because of the way the FFT algorithm is set up, the first element always represents the `t=0` element.

We can remedy the problem by performing an `ifftshift` operation before the FFT in order to shift the center to the first element. Note that for a sequence with even length, the element `x[N/2+1]` is assumed to be the center.

```
A1 = [ 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 ];        % A1 real, even sequence about A1(4)
B1 = fft(ifftshift(A1));       % B1 is a real, even sequence
C1 = fft(A1);                  % C1 is _not_ a real, even sequence
abs(B1) == abs(C1)             % B1 and C1 differ only in phase

A2 = [ 0 1 2 3 3 2 1 ];        % A2 real, even sequence about A2(0)
B2= fft(ifftshift(A2));        % B2 is _not_ a real, even sequence
C2= fft(A2);                   % C2 is a real, even sequence
abs(B2) == abs(C2)             % B2 and C2 differ only in phase
```

As you can see by the last example, it would be ***incorrect*** to say "***always*** use `ifftshift` before `fft`."  What if the first element of my data is already the `t=0` element? Then applying `ifftshift` would be the *wrong* thing to do.

## Summary

In general, `ifftshift` should only be used *before* applying an `fft`/`ifft`.  The `fft` and `ifft` functions always assume that the first element of your data represents `t=0` and `f=0` respectively. The main question you should ask yourself when using these functions is "where does `t=0` (or `f=0`) live in my data?" and "Where do I want them to live?"

In general, `fftshift` should only be used *after* applying an `fft`/`ifft`. The output of these functions is given such that the first element represents `f=0` and `t=0` respectively.  If you want to rearrange your data such that the `f=0` and `t=0` elements appear in the center, then `fftshift` is the right answer.

Without having a more thorough understanding of exactly what the data you are working with represents, it would be impossible to say whether any `ifftshift` or `fftshift` functions are necessary.  Note that there are many situations in which one might use `fft`/`fft2` and `ifft`/`ifft2` correctly without ever needing to invoke `fftshift` or `ifftshift`.

Comment: If the matrix has even dimensions, it seems like fftshift(fftshift(A)) is equal to the original matrix A. The same goes for ifftshift(ifftshift(A)).

Comment: Typo in the last example ?
B2= fft(ifftshift(A));        --> B2= fft(ifftshift(A2));